# Allure report, how I can init allure report to my site?

Tags: allure

I want to embed a report on my page, without launching a separate server for the report, can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Publish the report to your web server and make sure you have valid web.config file.

Your report should be accessible.

Web.config file I use is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you by "without launching a separate server" words you meant you don't have any web server then the answer - it's impossible.